# Cakephp BelongsTo

Tags: mysql, cakephp

If have a table with customers and one with addresses.

A Customer must have (only) one address but an address dont have to have a customer (depending on field Type). So i am just asking how to tell cake to get the customers address when finding a customer, but dont touch any customer when finding an address..

if you're going to start asking for any code, please read again i am sure its not necessary to post any code, i just need the right way to tell cake the relationships between those tables using $belongsTo, $hasOne, and stuff like that but i am not clear how to exactly do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that `Customer hasOne Address`.

But `Address` can be left without any associations to `Customer` and be bound to an association on the fly when needed or describe the association in the model and unbound it on the fly. You could even do that on one of the model's callbacks automatically.

It really depends on what you want to do, how many times you will need the data one way and how many the other and what you're trying to accomplish. But for cake, even not "hardwiring" any association is fine too, you will loose though some automagic.